# ReactJS: How to pin table header when scrolling out of view

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, css-tables

My page has a fixed 50px tall top navigation bar. It also has a table that currently scrolls up behind the navigation bar. I would like to pin the header below the nav bar when it touches it while scrolling up, so it is always in view.

I'm interested in guidance on the following:

1) In general, What is the best way to achieve this in React?

2) My current approach uses jquery to read positions and sizes of certain DOM elements. Is this considered an anti pattern in React? More specifically, this is what I'm attempting to do currently:

I fix the position of the table header row when the table scrolls to a certain position. This approach is not very pretty - as it requires me to assign a width to each column header element when I fix position the header row, otherwise the header width doesn't match the table width. I also need to listen for window resize events and update the header widths appropriately when the page is resized.

Comment: You could duplicate the header row and keep the original row to keep the width.

Comment: I've thought about duplicating it. It's tricky because the table columns are sortable, so any sort state would need to be kept in sync between the two header rows. This makes me think it might be better to just have one row, but update the position of it appropriately.

Comment: This has nothing to do with react, but is instead a general css question. If you add the appropriate tags you may get a higher visibility for people searching for css questions to answer

Comment: @marvinhagemeister thanks for the feedback. I added some css tags. However, I'm not sure that I agree that it has nothing to do with react. I'm interested in best practices - specifically the react ways to query the DOM data that I need to apply / un-apply the css styles. I've updated my question to better reflect that